# get exact html contents that were produced using a repeater

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, repeater

I am using a JS Library called Dragula. I am trying to use it to implement resorting of a list whose contents are produced using a repeater. My problem is that even if I resort the items (divs) of the list, if I get the info for each of the lists items in the codebehind using the repeater control, it does not know that a resorting has occurred, and can only return me the list items information in the same order that the repeater was populated in.

Is there a way to get the html contents of an html tag that itself is produced using a repeater and whose list contents are each produced using a reapter as well.

Example of my situation in code:

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpSearchResults">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <section id="task-list" class="task-area_tasks-container taskorder-group">

                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpTaskGroup">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <div id="task" class="task" runat="server">
                          <span>some info needed retrieved in order</span>
                        </div>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </section>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

in-browser HTML (unsorted):
[image: You can tell the sorting of the list items by the second "ct##" part of the dynamically created id]

You can tell the sorting of the list items by the second "ct##" part of the dynamically created id

inbrowser HTML (sorted):
[image]

You can tell the sorting of the list items by the second "ct##" part of the dynamically created id. If you notice, they are sorted differently now.

The problem is that if I trigger a codebehind method, I can get the info from each of the repeater lists in the original order (1st picture), but not in the new order (2nd picture). Is there any way for me to retrieve the new ordering? Thanks in advance!

This is how I am getting the repeater items information currently, but this will only get it in the original ordering:

```
For Each search As RepeaterItem In rpSearchResults.Items
            Dim rpTaskGroup As Repeater = search.FindControl("rpTaskGroup")

            For Each task As RepeaterItem In rpTaskGroup.Items
                TaskOrderID = task.FindControl("task_order_id")
                arTOIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(TaskOrderID.InnerText))
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Might be a bit too obvious; but are you sure these elements have already been sorted when you're trying to access them?

(In other words, if you run this in an onDocumentReady-callback and at the same time the sorting starts, it may be well possible that the list hasn't been sorted when your code gets executed).

Can you give an example of when you're calling your methods and when the lists are sorted?

Comment: This is the order that things happen in: 1) page loads and other ondocumentready functions take place. 2) drag list items around to re order them. 3) click a asp:linkbutton to trigger the codebehind function to retrieve the informaiton of the list items

Comment: I believe the reason for it getting the informaiton in the original ordering is because it is using the repeater control to get the information, and the ordering of the items is static once the items have been attached to the repeater, no matter what takes place on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a work around to the problem that I had. It is not the cleanest in the world, but as far as my knowledge it is the only way to do what I am trying to do in this instance.

1) I created a way to trigger a javascript function that would retrieve the information in the divs in the correct order

2) I stored all the ordered information of the divs in a variable that I then attached to an asp:HiddenField element to later be retrieved in the code behind

3) at the end of the javascript function I trigger a click on a asp:LinkButton element that would trigger a code behind event handler. In this event handler I then retrieved the ordered information from the HiddenField and used it as needed.

Hope this helps anyone who was having the same problems as myself. As I said, maybe not the cleanest or simplest way to do it, but it is the only way I could find after hours and hours of searching, and, if done right, it could be somewhat clean.